# How can I use push() to add an element at the end of an array

Tags: html, arrays, push, element

I am using basic html/javascript. I want to put "sss" at the end of the array, but the "sss" is being placed next to every element in the array as shown below.

```
 183.2500
    sss183.0800
    sss185.5800
    sss190.6500
    sss183.5800
    sss182.8450
    sss180.9700
    sss184.0300
    sss177.1400
    sss170.4300
    sss172.2100
    sss174.0500
    sss167.8400
    sss163.7800
    sss161.1500
    sss167.5100
    sss166.1900
    sss167.4000
    sss166.6800
    sss
```

I only want "sss" placed at the very end of the array. What am I doing wrong? I am using the `push()` method but it doesn't seem to be working correctly

```js
fetch('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&outputsize=full&apikey=DEMO')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    appendData(data);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('error: ' + err);
  });

function appendData(data) {
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
  var arrw = ["2020-02-14",
    "2020-02-13",
    "2020-02-12",
    "2020-02-11",
    "2020-02-10",
    "2020-02-07",
    "2020-02-06",
    "2020-02-05",
    "2020-02-04",
    "2020-02-03",
    "2020-01-31",
    "2020-01-30",
    "2020-01-29",
    "2020-01-28",
    "2020-01-27",
    "2020-01-24",
    "2020-01-23",
    "2020-01-22",
    "2020-01-21",
  ];
  arrw.push("ssss");
  var fff;

  for (var i = 0; i < arrw.length; i++) {
    fff = [data['Time Series (Daily)'][arrw[i]]['1. open'], "</br>"];
    fff.push("sss");
    for (var c = 0; c < fff.length; c++) {
      document.write(fff[c]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: if you simply want to push "sss" in the end of the `arrw`, you simply do `arrw.push("sss")`, no need for any extra code

Comment: Do not push the string in the for loop